# Table binding with Angular

Tags: angularjs, model-binding, handsontable

I'm trying to make a table footer auto-update but the ng-repeat and even the regular double-braces does not appear to auto-bind when the $scope value is updated.

https://jsfiddle.net/r0pk793e/3/

Specifically, I'm setting the value $scope.hello and incrementing it when the table updates (when the user changes a value in the table cells). Though I can see the value changes, it does not get re-bound to the HTML.

I believe this table should be  updated by the following function, but it is not...

```
  <table class="tg">
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-yw4l" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The $scope.hello does change, as illustrated by the `console.log($scope.hello);`

```
  var doUpdate = function () {
    var items = [];

    for (var c = 0; c < headings.length; c++) {
      if (typeof (hot.getDataAtCell(0, c)) == "number") {
        var levelTotal = 0;
        var i = 0;

        do {
          levelTotal += hot.getDataAtCell(i, c);
          i++;
        } while (hot.getDataAtCell(i, c) != null);

        items.push(levelTotal);
      }
      else
      {
        items.push(' ');
      }
    }

    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.hello = $scope.hello + 1;
    console.log($scope.hello);
  }
```

Comment: your `$scope.hello` indeed changes if you see in console, but its not rendering into html

Comment: Because your doUpdate function is not attached to $scope so angular is not aware of that change, hence it is not updated, here is the modified code https://jsfiddle.net/r0pk793e/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested your fiddle everything got updated

[image]

anyway if this still not working call $scope.$apply(); after updating your values and you will see the magic happening.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you - $apply() was needed. I think because the update is happening within the handsontable event listener. The update time I'm actually looking for is when the table content is changed by the user.